# Hide a title in Joomla only for desktop users

Tags: php, joomla

My site: http://bgu-online.de/index.php/de/

I have a problem. I'm using Joomla 3.2.
My site has a mobile view. For some reasons sometimes you accidentally get to the dektop page. But that is not the problem. For this issue I have put a link (named MOBIL) in my topbar which leads the mobile phone user back to the mobile version. Now I want that the dekstop users won't see this link, because its not gone work for them, if they click on it.
NOTE: Only the smartphone users should see this link!

How do i realise this in Joomla?

Thanks for your help
Greetings from Germany :)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for how to formulate your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a CSS3 media query for this.

Firstly, give you link a class like so:

```
<a class="mobile" href="#">View mobile site</a>
```

Then target this class in your template CSS file for a minimum screen width:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .item-883 a {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This will basically hide your link on screen widths that are 768px or above.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but where i have to put:
<a class="mobile" href="#">View mobile site</a>
in joomla?

Comment: Well you already have a button that the user clicks on to view the mobile site. I assume this is somewhere in your template index.php file. I'm not sure if you added it yourself or if it comes with your template. So where ever the link code is located, simple add the class to it. If you would like to provide a link to your site, I could take a look for you which might speed up the process

Comment: I already put a link to my site :). The Link is in the topbar named "Mobil". The link is a menu entry with an extern url

Comment: Ahh it's a menu item. In which case inspect the element using Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools to get the class.

Comment: it's: <li class="item-883">
<a href="/index.php/de/2011-03-23-15-41-53/ueberarbeitung-der-homepage?device=auto">Mobil</a>

Comment: I have updated my code. It should work for you now. Just add the CSS code I have provided to your template css file. Don't worry about adding any class, this shouldn't be required now

Comment: OK thanks, now it worked :) OMG thats so cool. Many thanks to you